# How can I plot a vector of y-values in ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How do I plot a vector of y-values in `ggplot2`?

```
 pValues_Both <- c(0.004079,0.4392,0.6882,0.02053,0.4849,0.4938,0.3379,0.8408,0.07067,0.6603,0.2547,0.8692,0.8946,0.0696,0.6206,0.9559,0.9119,0.5162,0.2469,0.1582)
```

I have tried the following:

```
pValues_Both.m <- melt(pValues_Both)

ggplot(pValues_Both.m, aes(y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`geom_bar()` needs also `x` values to make the barplot. One workaround would be to provide just sequence of numbers that are the same lenght as `value`.

```
ggplot(pValues_Both.m, aes(x=seq_along(value),y=value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's also a ggplot `qplot` 1-liner w/o having to pre-make a data frame (it does it for you), but the same basic principle as Didzis':

```
qplot(x=1:length(pValues_Both), y=pValues_Both, geom="bar", 
    stat="identity", xlab="", ylab="", main="pValues_Both")
```

[image]

Comment: Getting this message ```Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
In addition: Warning message:
`stat` is deprecated```

Comment: 'Warning: `qplot()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.'

Answer (score 0):

`qplot` creates the dataframe for you if not supplied. The plot you want is called a col plot in `ggplot`, so:

```
pVals = c(.0041,.4392,.6882,.02053,.4849,.4938,.3379,.8408,.07067,.6603,.2547,.8692,.8946,.0696,.6206,.9559,.9119,.5162,.2469,.1582)

qplot(x = 1:20, y = pVals, geom = "col")
```

Comment: Warning: `qplot()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.